# How to prevent Lock Timeout in Mysql Update Table with millions request

Tags: mysql

I have problem with one table from mysql. 
Struktur table like this :

[image]

Every table_detail will insert every a minutes. And user need to show all off detail data in on page. So, i create table_header that collect all last data from every table_detail.

But the problems is, Table_header lock because milion request update to this table.
How to resolved this problem ? 
I have already set 
innodb_lock_wait_timeout 100
innodb_write_io_threads 24

Thanks anyway

Comment: Updates / inserts should not block selects, unless you try to place locks on the records while selecting them (for update, shared mode).

Comment: I have 2 MySQL, there are replication. One for just read and the other just for update and insert. So this blocked from other updates at Table_Header. Because 10000 update every minutes on Table_Header

Comment: Can we see your main `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries, and outputs of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both `Table_Detail_1` and `Table_Header` please?

Comment: In that server not use SELECT, just INSERT in table_detail_1 untuk table_detail_xxxx and UPDATE to Table_Header.
Index in Table_Header is ID_Detail and Flag.
Structur table just like on this diagram.

SELECT Query on other Server with Read Replica.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not fully understand your comments! Are you saying that the amount of replicated inserts / updates block Table_Header in the read replica from being read?

Comment: Hello @Shadow, 
Table_Header in one second there are hundreds of UPDATE requests. then there is a UPDATE request that timeout.
Table_Header has never been a SELECT request, only UPDATE.

Comment: In this case you need help in configuring mysql, not with code. This question should be moved to the dba sister site of SO.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow, So there is no option to perform structure update ? As you know, How many update there are mysql can handle ?

Comment: We fo not have enough information to judge that. Strictly speaking, your table_header table is a denormalised table that is used to aggregate data to speed up queries. You can replace it with a view. Whether this is better, I do not know, you need to test it. Mysql does not have a limit on the number of updates it can perform. The underlying server does through its capacity limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. @shadow
After use SAAS Mysql server & recommendation from google cloud sql - we create replication server. 1 Server for INSERT/UPDATE and other server for SELECT.
But cost server very high.
After research - not all transaction in data will store in mysql - we use scylladb for handle high request.
Thanks all